# SyntaxError when writing IE9 html[lang] selectors in LESS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, less, less-mixins

I have a LESS mixin with rule-set to make IE9 hack selectors:

```
.ie9(@rules) {
  html[lang='\
en'] & { @rules(); }
}
```

Hack source: http://browserhacks.com/#hack-e6b158b7e27bcb157326348efb5c0bb2

But after compiling I see:

> SyntaxError: expected ']' got ''' in src/less/mixins.less on line 75, column 13:
>
> 74 .ie9(@rules) {
> 75   html[lang='\
> 76 ru'] & { @rules(); }

How to fix this in LESS?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating the OP-confirmed solution from [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665628/syntaxerror-when-writing-ie9-htmllang-selectors-in-less#comment53177424_32665628) by [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry) to an answer:</sub>

> It [won't] compile in v2.4.0 -- it'll give the same error indicated in question. If you upgrade the compiler [to v2.5.1], then it should compile without any errors.